# If statement with 2 conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

I was practising statements and ran into a problem. I'm trying to make it so that if `$child3` is available, then it will `echo` all three children, like how when `$child2` is available, it `echo`s Kim & Pom. What did I do wrong?

```
$child = "Kim";
$child2 = "Pom";
$child3 = "Rob";

if($child2) {
    echo $child; echo " "; echo $child2;
} elseif($child3) {
    echo $child; echo " "; echo $child2; echo " "; echo $child3;
} else {
    echo $child;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the behavior you want more clearly and thoroughly?

Comment: You are using If - Else-if blocks. So if the first condition is satisfied ($child2) it will skip the rest of the code. If you want every condition to be checked you need three If blocks, not Else-if

Comment: switch\case would be easier and clearer.

Comment: @Dagon: how would you switch on 3 different variables? I doubt it would turn out clearer.

Comment: @Dagon: It definitely wouldn't turn out clearer, given the order. But I don't think that's the point... otherwise, an array would definitely be the best solution.

Comment: thanks for the edit minitech.

Comment: Why do you check with "if". What is the actual variable value when it returns false? Is it false or null or empty string or zero?

Comment: @Juventus18: Yeah, I was going to add that, but... it's not really clearer, just "cleverer" :)

Comment: @minitect: Juventus18's code is wrong, it tries to print child2 and child3 even if they are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing the conditions:

```
$child = "Kim";
$child2 = "Pom";
$child3 = "Rob";

if($child3){
    echo $child . " " . $child2 . " " . $child3;
}else if($child2){
    echo $child . " " . $child2;
}else{
    echo $child;
}
```

You might also like the wonderful string concatenation operator `.`.

Comment: `elseif` is valid in PHP, by the way.

Comment: I'd also consider using a `switch` statement. Either that or put children in an array and loop using `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

`elseif` only executes if none of the preceding `if`s or `elseif`s executed. So you'll want to move it above the other `if`:

```
if($child3) {
    echo $child; echo " "; echo $child2; echo " "; echo $child3;
} elseif($child2) {
    echo $child; echo " "; echo $child2;
} else {
    echo $child;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want something like this:

```
$child = 1; // Or $child = 2; Or $child = 3;

if ($child == 1) {
    echo 'Kim';
} elseif ($child == 2) {
    echo 'Pom';
} else {
    echo 'Rob';
}
```

But I recommend `switch()` as soon as you have `elseif`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$child = "Kim";
$child2 = "Pom";
$child3 = "Rob";

if($child3){
    echo $child; echo " "; echo $child2; echo " "; echo $child3;
}elseif($child2){
    echo $child; echo " "; echo $child2;
}else{
    echo $child;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's your actual code, you'll only ever get `Kim Rob`, as `$child2` will always be `true`, thereby bypassing your `else` clauses.

Also, you can combine your `echo`s into:

```
echo "$child $child2 $child3";
```

It makes it far easier to read that way.

Comment: and also produces a bunch of warnings.

Comment: What warnings?  Variable interpolation has been a part of PHP for at least a decade.

Comment: if $child3 is not defined and you run PHP with E_NOTICE, you'll get a warning in the output.

Comment: OP's code does not produce such errors, he checks with "if" to see if variable is defined, you do not.

Comment: I didn't write a full solution.  I merely wanted to point out the flaw in the OP's logic.  I'm well aware about the necessity of checking whether or not a variable actually contains a value

Comment: But if you add checking, your code would look completely different and surely would not so "easy to read" compared to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if ($child) {
   echo "{$child} ";
}
if ($child2) {
   echo "{$child2} ";
}
if ($child3) {
   echo "{$child3} ";
}
```

Comment: This is most probably what he really want's to do, although it is unclear from question.

Comment: Did you mean ${child} or really {$child} and why not just $child?

Comment: @MilanBabuškov I think he wants to show all defined values​​.

Comment: I mean: why the curly brackets? {}

Comment: @MilanBabuškov I always use curly syntax. For more information look here [Complex (curly) syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex). Of course, in this example variables can used without curly brackets.

Comment: I know how curly braces works. I just wanted to know why you used it, because it is not needed at all and only makes code harder to read.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov As I said, I always use the this syntax, and it seems to me that so is much easier to read (see this [example](https://gist.github.com/2916888); and GitHub is not the only one who apply different style for curly variables). Rather, it is a matter of habit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. I agree with Dragon that a switch would be clearer/better.

```
switch (true)
{
  case (isset($child,$child2,$child3)) : 
    echo $child . ' ' . $child2 . ' ' . $child3;
    break;
  case (isset($child, $child2)) :
    echo $child . ' ' . $child2;
    break;
  case (isset($child)) :
    echo $child;
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Suppose only $child is defined, it would still try to echo $child2 and $child3.

Comment: And you're missing ) in the second "case". Try running the code.

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't want to be throwing notices all over the place. I've fixed it.